# Bootstrap not detecting change in screen size between col-lg and col-md screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to figure out why this is happening, I am working on a fluid layout which is fluid till 1366px screen size and after that it is fixed, except header.

Now if I change my screen size anywhere between 1200px to 1366px then it does not make any change in html elements and instead a horizontal scroll bar appears. If I go beyond 1200px to anywhere till 300px or something it scales very well. But I don't know why is it having issue between 1200 to 1366px screen size.

**ISSUE:** I don't want horizontal scroll bar to come between 1200px to 1366px and make content scale accordingly, as it scales for other screen size.

And this issue is not on a single page, it is on complete website. You can see this issue happening on this website [Winni.in](http://www.winni.in)

Any idea, where I am going wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the issue between 1200 and 1366?

Comment: I don't want horizontal scroll bar to come between 1200px to 1366px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears because you have this declaration in your CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
  .container {
    width: 1330px;
  }
}
```

Which means that starting from screen width 1200, the div will be 1330px. Just change it to 1200px or 100%, depending what result you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed out exact thing. I changed min-width to 1340px and it is working fine now. With width 100% it was still giving a scroll bar, not that big but a little one

Comment: One more thing I would like to know, is it perfectly normal - appearance of a horizontal scroll bar between a little range of screen size. Like if you see this website now then between 1202px to 1222px a little horizontal scroll bar appears, similarly on some other little ranges it also appears. Is it normal with everybody or only I am encountering this? (Please do force reload - override old css)

Comment: You have to understand that the grid syntax is strict. It HAS to be .container > .row > col-*. In your current code, it's .container > .home-featured-products > .row > .col-*.

Comment: The scrollbar appears because, once again, you were not strict to the grid. <div class="container" style="padding-left:5px; margin-left:10px;">. Modifying left or right margins/paddings of grid elements is not allowed.

Comment: Okay, previously I was not paying attention to it. But later I did coded according to the standard. I will refactor it, thanks :)